# Completar campos

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Ao selecionar o produto na lista de sugestões AutoComplete tenho que dar TAB para completar os próximos campos, queria que a medida que o campo Descrição fosse preenchido os outros campos fossem preenchidos sem necessidadade do usuário utilizar TAB. Teria como ?

```html
    <div class="container">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-lg-12">  
                 <h3 align="center">Autocomplete utilizando jQuery, PHP e MySQL</h3><br />  
                 <label>Descrição</label>  
                 <input type="text" name="descri" id="descri" class="form-control" placeholder="Escreva aqui a descrição do produto"><br>  
                 <div id="descriList"></div>  
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4"><!-- Inicio Input Cóodigo do Produto-->
                 <label for="ex1">Código do Produto:</label>
                 <input type="text" required class="form-control" maxlength="13" name="codigo_produto"><br>
             </div><!-- Fim Input Código do Produto -->

             <div class="col-lg-4"><!-- Inicio Input Código EAN / Barcode -->
                 <label for="ex1">Código EAN:</label>
                 <input type="text" required class="form-control" maxlength="13" name="barcode"><br>
             </div><!-- Fim Input Código EAN / Barcode -->

             <div class="col-lg-4"><!-- Inicio Input ID -->
                 <label for="ex1">ID:</label>
                 <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" maxlength="13" name="id"><br>
             </div><!-- Fim Input ID -->
       </div>
    </div>
  </body>  
 </html>
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#descri').keyup(function(){  
       var query = $(this).val();  
       if(query != '')  
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"search.php",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:{query:query},  
                 success:function(data)  
                 {  
                      $('#descriList').fadeIn();  
                      $('#descriList').html(data);  
                 }  
            });  
       }  
  });  
  $(document).on('click', 'li', function(){  
       $('#descri').val($(this).text());  
       $('#descriList').fadeOut().change();  
  });  
 });  
 
$("input[name='descri']").on("change",function(){
 alert("Campo alterado!");
        var $codigo_produto = $("input[name='codigo_produto']");
        var $barcode = $("input[name='barcode']");
        var $id = $("input[name='id']");
        var $unid = $("select[name='unid']");
        var $familia = $("select[name='familia']");
        var $tipo = $("select[name='tipo']");
        var $id_depto = $("select[name='id_depto']");
        var $grupo = $("select[name='grupo']");
        var $cod_referencial = $("input[name='cod_referencial']");
        var $codigo_interno = $("input[name='codigo_interno']");

        $.getJSON('function.php',{ 
                descricao: $( this ).val() 
        },function( json ){
                $codigo_produto.val( json.codigo_produto );
                $barcode.val( json.barcode );
                $id.val( json.id );
                $unid.val( json.unid );
                $familia.val( json.familia );
                $tipo.val ( json.tipo );
                $id_depto.val( json.id_depto );
                $grupo.val( json.grupo );
                $cod_referencial.val( json.cod_referencial );
                $codigo_interno.val( json.codigo_interno );
        });
});
 </script>
```

Comment: Se quiser que a função seja executada cada vez que algo é digitado no campo, basta usar `$("input[name='descri']").on("input",function(){})`.

Comment: queria que a função fosse executada ao clicar em algo sugerido pela lista do autoComplete e preenchesse o campo input de name descrição

Comment: Coloca `$("input[name='descri']").on("change",function(){`

Comment: ja tentei e não funciona, sera que devo alterar o segundo script

Comment: Aqui funcionou, veja um teste: http://decknorte.com/teste.php

Comment: digita qualquer coisa no campo "descrição" e depois clica em qualquer <li> que vai aparecer

Comment: no caso o autocomplete funciona, aparecem os dados relacionados a pesquisa no campo 'descrição' porém ao selecionar algo / clicar em algo, invés de completar os campos logo que o campo descrição é preenchido, tenhoq que dar TAB para que ocorra a execução da segunda função e ai sim completar os próximos campos

Comment: Não não. Veja o alert, já entrou na função que vai completar os outros campos.

Comment: Precisa dar TAB não. Ao clicar na <li> ele preenche o campo "descrição" e chama a função pros outros campos.

Comment: Mudei o código lá pra preencher os campos. Veja que funciona perfeitamente ao clicar numa <li>: http://decknorte.com/teste.php

Comment: no caso no meu código ele não funciona,só reconhece o que foi digitado no campo input, editei a pergunta para mostar como esta

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67520/discussion-between-dvd-and-victor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal é fazer uma função normal para receber o `click` na `<li>` do *autocomplete*. Mudei também a posição da *listener* `$("#descriList li").on` para dentro do retorno do primeiro Ajax, para que seja delegado o `click` nas `<li>` dinâmicas, e consequentemente chamar a função que preenche os demais campos.

O código ficou assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#descri').keyup(function(){  
       var query = $(this).val();  
       if(query != '')  
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"search.php",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:{query:query},  
                 success:function(data)  
                 {  
                      $('#descriList').fadeIn();  
                      $('#descriList').html(data);  
                        $("#descriList li").on('click', function(){ 
                            $('#descri').val($(this).text());  
                           $('#descriList').fadeOut().change();
                           atualiza_campos(); 
                    });  
                 }  
            });  
       }  
  });  
 });

function atualiza_campos(){
        var $codigo_produto = $("input[name='codigo_produto']");
        var $barcode = $("input[name='barcode']");
        var $id = $("input[name='id']");
        var $unid = $("select[name='unid']");
        var $familia = $("select[name='familia']");
        var $tipo = $("select[name='tipo']");
        var $id_depto = $("select[name='id_depto']");
        var $grupo = $("select[name='grupo']");
        var $cod_referencial = $("input[name='cod_referencial']");
        var $codigo_interno = $("input[name='codigo_interno']");

        $.getJSON('function.php',{ 
                descricao: $( '#descri' ).val() 
        },function( json ){
                $codigo_produto.val( json.codigo_produto );
                $barcode.val( json.barcode );
                $id.val( json.id );
                $unid.val( json.unid );
                $familia.val( json.familia );
                $tipo.val ( json.tipo );
                $id_depto.val( json.id_depto );
                $grupo.val( json.grupo );
                $cod_referencial.val( json.cod_referencial );
                $codigo_interno.val( json.codigo_interno );
        });
}
```

Comment: obrigado resolveu jusamente como precisava

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode alterar o evento `blur` para `keyup`:

```
 $("input[name='descri']").keyup(function(){})
```

Comment: No caso ja tentei isso, porém não sei se por já ter uma função embaixo com este evento entra em conflito, mas não funciona. Queria que ao receber o click na sugestão do autoComplete, já fossem preenchidos os campos,

Comment: se voce consegue com estes dois eventos sem conflitar teria como alterar o código e mostrar onde estão os erros ?

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/137589)

Comment: @DvD você conseguiria ajudar na solução

Comment: Por que voce esta usando dois eventos `ready` @Victor? Talvez possa vincular ambas as acoes em somente um `keyup`..

Comment: @LucasCosta eu tentei e não consegui, editei meu código e e vou repostar, você poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Claro @Victor. Te convido para conversamos no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67512/chat-with-victor)